# Segmentation fault (Invalid permissions for mapped object [0x7f5aa747f360])

Tags: gazebo

When I run `ign gazebo`, I got an error:

Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 2962:
#0    Object "[0x7f5aa747f360]", at 0x7f5aa747f360, in
Segmentation fault (Invalid permissions for mapped object [0x7f5aa747f360])

What should I do? Help me!!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Trác Minh. When I google your error, I see a result about two versions of boost libraries on the same computer. Can you please *edit your question* to include details of how you [installed gazebo](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.